# Run powershell command with quote marks via cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, quotes

I need to run a powershell command via CMD

my command is

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "ACPI Thermal Zone"')
[1].GetDeviceProperties().DeviceProperties  |
Select-Object -Property keyName, data
```

and i get successful result:
[image]

However, when i try to run the same command with cmd, I getting exception in the query execution.
it looks like something with the quote marks in the command.

Cmd command

```
powershell -command "(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "ACPI Thermal 
Zone"')"
```

Cmd error
[image]

Please help, what do i miss?

#### Edit

I tried double quotes and escape char with no luck
[image]

Comment: tried, still didn't get it work

Comment: Isn't **`** the escape character for PS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might resolve this at a ***CMD* level** by escaping the double quotes with a backslash (`\"`):

```
PowerShell -command "Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like \"ACPI Thermal Zone\"'"
```

... or as WMI queries also accepts [single quotes for names in filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wql#using-the-escape-character).
You might also simply avoid the double quotes in the WMI query and resolve this with (escaped) single quotes (`''`) at a ***PowerShell* level**:

```
PowerShell -command "(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like ''ACPI Thermal Zone''')"
```